# What does "Red tape" refer to?

Tags: idioms

What does "Red tape" refer to?

Comment: I liked the other answers as well, why did the authors delete them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **Definition:**
>   Official routine or procedure marked
>   by excessive complexity which results
>   in delay or inaction .
>
> **Example:** You would not believe the red tape involved in getting the required permits.
>
> **Origin:** From the red tape formerly used to bind legal documents in England
>
> **First Known Use:** 1736

Source: [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-tape?show=0&t=1284039920)

Comment: I wonder if ribbon cutting (as in opening a  building) is in reference to red tape...

Comment: @burnt_hand: I can't imagine there being any kind of authoritative source on this, but I'd guess it's much more akin to cutting the ribbon on a gift package.